# How to add http headers in WSGI middleware?

Tags: python, wsgi

How can http headers be added within a WSGI middleware?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've found a nice example from the [pylons book](http://pylonsbook.com/en/1.1/the-web-server-gateway-interface-wsgi.html#changing-the-status-and-headers).

```
class Middleware(object):
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):

        def custom_start_response(status, headers, exc_info=None):
            headers.append(('Set-Cookie', "name=value"))
            return start_response(status, headers, exc_info)

        return self.app(environ, custom_start_response)
```

The trick is to use a nested method.